# Entity Framework query to populate viewmodel with keyvaluepairs, keyvaluepairs with too many arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have three model classes in my code-first model.

```
public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public guid ProjectTypeId{ get; set; }
    public string projectType{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }
    //more properties here
    //...
    public bool Activated{ get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectDetail> ProjectDetails{ get; set; }
}
```

As you can see a project has many details.

```
public class ProjectDetail
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Project Project{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProjectId{ get; set; }             
    public string DetailDescription{ get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectDetailsAnswer> ProjectDetailsAnswers{ get; set; }
}
```

And a projectDetail has many answers:

```
public class ProjectDetailsAnswer
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProjectDetailId{ get; set; }
    public ProjectDetail ProjectDetail{ get; set; }       
    public string OtherField{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string AnswerDescription{ get; set; }
}
```

This is my viewmodel

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> Details { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to populate that viewmodel with a keyvaluepair

```
var data = _dbContext.Project
                    .Select(p => new ProjectViewModel
                                  {
                                      Id = p.Id,
                                      Details = p.ProjectDetails
                                                 .Select(pd => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(pd.DetailDescription, pd.ProjectDetailsAnswers.Select(pda => pda.AnswerDescription).ToList())
                                                 .ToList()
                                  })
                    .ToList();
```

However I get this error

> KeyValuePair does not contain a constructor that takes that many arguments.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I get that error for no reason too. And it's just on a line by itself - no query or anything complicated.

Comment: I think that the problem exist in what platform your using. try using dictionary instead. otherwise what platform are you using? i tested this code in .Net46 and its working just fine.

Comment: You are just missing one more closing brace after `Select(pda => pda.AnswerDescription).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out there was a typo "bad escape sequence" a couple lines up in my code in a string. Totally unrelated to the KeyValuePair line.

[image]